# Why am I recieving TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have included jquery only once and yet I am not able to get datatables to initiate on an html table. I have used both Firefox and Chrome dev toolbars and I can see these libs are loading.

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/datatables/js/dataTables.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/create.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

In the create.js file, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#gridEmployees').DataTable({
        paging: true
    });
}
```

Looking at others who recieved this error, their problem seemed to be either referencing jquery more than once or placing the datatables lib ahead of jquery. As you can see, I have not made either of those mistakes.

Comment: Is the JS file really named `dataTables.dataTables.min.js`? I suspect it's actually `dataTables.min.js`

Comment: Yeah, I used this new-ish tool named libman and I can confirm the path and filename are correct.

Comment: Okay, you got me thinking and I just tried jquery.dataTables.min.js and that got it working. I don't see any documentation on which files do what. That would be helpful to have.

Comment: `jquery.dataTables.min.js` contains the jQuery DataTables library. The documentation on how to download the library should make that clear.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you say that you could see in the console that the libraries are loading. You should have gotten a 404 error for the misnamed file.

Comment: Right, I verified that the dataTables.dataTables.min.js was loaded by the browser. Unfortunatly this was the wrong library to be using.